# Azure file sync unable to create cloud endpoint Code:2134347771

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-files

[image]I was adding cloud endpoint from command line as well as portal for  Azure File Sync setup.
It throws error Cloud endpoint creation failed

Ay workaround to fix this ?

Cloud endpoint 'azuremfileshare'
Code: -2134347771
Details: Failed to provision a replica group.

Comment: Can u share what commands you are trying to add Cloud endpoint?

Comment: az storagesync sync-group cloud-endpoint create --resource-group "azurefileshr" --storage-sync-service "esngsrjtest" --sync-group-name "SampleSyncGroup" --name "SampleCloudEndpoint" --storage-account esngsrjstrone --azure-file-share-name azuremfileshare

Comment: But now it fixed first  we need to enable SMB 3.1 form storage file share

Comment: Let's give your solution in the answer and accept it so it can be helpful for the community.